Format open date ranges as 'from XXXX' in biblatex
I have a custom .bbx file for my CV, which includes code for laying out entries which represent education, e.g.
@Degree{foo,
    date = {2018-10-01/},
    institution = {University of Life},
    degree = {Visiting studentship},
    advisor = {Smith, John}
}

I want to customise the way biblatex prints date ranges with printdate (or similar commands), as these are used in the bibenvironment. Open ended ranges (like above) should be printed 'from YEAR' (even if they are more specific), so the above should render 'from 2018'. Otherwise, I want everything to behave as with the option date=year. How can I do this?
Here's a MWE of what I have so far:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  datamodel=biblatex-cv,
  date=year
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Degree{foo,
    date = {2018-10-01/},
    institution = {University of Life},
    degree = {Visiting studentship},
    advisor = {Smith, John}
}
\end{filecontents}

\defbibenvironment{cv}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item[\printdate]}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{degree}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{degree}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=cv]

\end{document}

which delivers:

Whereas I want:


It's probably the most sensible (if not shortest) option to change the internal date printing macros.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  datamodel=biblatex-cv,
  date=year
]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{from}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  from = {from},
}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\mkdaterangefull}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[{#2date}]{%
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
              {\bibstring{from}\addspace}
              {}}%
         \datecircaprint
         % Such a year division component can only come from an ISO8601 year division which replaces
         % a normal month so if it exists, we know that a normal date print is ruled out
         \iffieldundef{#2yeardivision}
           {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
            % Optionally print the time after the date
            \blx@printtime{#2}{}}
           {\csuse{mkbibyeardivisiondate#1}{#2year}{#2yeardivision}}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \dateeraprint{#2year}%
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
              {}
              {\bibdaterangesep
               \enddatecircaprint
               \iffieldundef{#2endyeardivision}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}%
                  % Optionally print the time after the date
                  \blx@printtime{#2}{end}}
                 {\csuse{mkbibyeardivisiondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endyeardivision}}%
               \enddateuncertainprint
               \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother



\defbibenvironment{cv}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item[\printdate]}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{degree}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{degree}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Degree{foo,
  date        = {2018-10-01/},
  institution = {University of Life},
  degree      = {Visiting studentship},
  advisor     = {Smith, John}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=cv]
\end{document}



Thank you for this @moewe -- it works perfectly in a single .tex (as in my/your mwe) but if I move your code (i.e. \makeatletter to \makeatother) to my .bbx file, then I get an error:
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:16291: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> blx@file@\blx 
              @cbxfile.cbx
l.16291 \RequireCitationStyle{\blx@cbxfile}

Is there some way to keep the code out of the way in the .bbx?

@modallyFragile If you want to move the code the .bbx file you need to drop the \makeatletter and \makeatother because they are already implied.
